# In Vim, is it possible to set a variable based on the first lines in the file that is being opened?

Tags: csv, vim, autocmd

I would like `vim` to detect and store the number of commented lines (prefixed with `#`) from the start of a file and then use a variable with the stored value to change a vim-setting in a file-specific manner.

**Example:**

If I open this file:

```
# Comment here
# and here
file text starts here
```

I want the variable to store `2`, and then use that value to set which line to start highlighting at (specifically with `csv_headerline=` in the csv-vim package). The number of commented lines would change from file to file.

I thought there might be a way to use `autocmd` and set up my `.vimrc` to have `vim` look through the first few lines of the file before opening it, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: There's probably a nicer way, but you could `/^[^#]` to go to the first line which doesn't start with a comment character, and `echo line('.')` to get the current line number, subtract one. But it's going to break if you have empty lines, comments mixed with empty lines, then code.

Answer (score 0):

Guided by @TesselatingHeckler's comment, I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Detect comments and identify the header line in csv-files                                                                                                                                                         
autocmd Filetype csv /^[^#] " Place cursor on first non-comment line                                                                                                                                                 
autocmd Filetype csv let b:csv_headerline=line('.') " Set cursor line as csv_headerline                                                                                                                              
autocmd Filetype csv CSVInit " Update vim.csv plugin to be aware of the new headerline
```

(When passing these commands directly to `vim -c` I had to write `line('.')+1`, not sure why).

So far it is working with both only commented lines in the beginning of the file and a mix of commented lines and empty lines (limited testing)!